# Create a Data Frame with unique values in one column and multiple values in the other column

Tags: python-2.7

I really need your help with something that I am struggling with.
I have a pandas data frame in python that looks like this=>

```
> 15   tag1
> 15   tag2
> 15   tag3
> 70   tag5
> 71   tag6
> 71   tag7
```

What I would need to have is something like:

```
15    tag1 tag2 tag3
70    tag5
71    tag6 tag7
```

and so on.
Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: may i comment that this dataframe will be something like a merge of dataframes.one dataframe that contains the unique values in one column and another dataframe as shown in the first paradigma